# Div for float numbers c++

Tags: c++, division, modulo, integer-division, truncation

I was wondering if a function like [`div`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/div/) exists for float numbers in C++. If I need both the integral division result and the remainder, `div` provides that:

For example:

```
const auto foo = div(5, 2);
const auto quot = foo.quot; // This will be 2
const auto rem = foo.rem; // This will be 1
```

But this doesn't work with `float`s. Trying to do `div(0.4, 0.8)` gives the compiler error:

> 'div': ambiguous call to overloaded function

How can I use `div` for `float`s?

Comment: Add .0 to your number, like 5/2.0.

Comment: Please define *"it wont work"*, and provide [mcve].

Comment: "It won't work" What exactly are you expecting will happen and what happens instead?

Comment: When i say it wont work i mean that, for example i want 0.4/0.8 to return 0 like the div function if it were 4/8.

Comment: You probably meant the modulo operator didn't work?

Comment: "it won't work" What did you try? What did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: do you mean `floor`? isn't that in `math.h` or something?

Comment: There is a [`fmod()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) in the standard library.

Comment: @PeteBecker I thought so too. Sadly that's wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34767710/2642059

Comment: @JonathanMee - you're right. I've deleted my comment.

Comment: @Bob__ You can't use `remainder`. It works like `remquo` which also doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34767710/2642059

Comment: @JonathanMee you are right, for `std::remainder` In contrast to `std::fmod()`, the returned value is not guaranteed to have the same sign as x.

Comment: @Bob__ Your comment is very helpful without that though. So in lieu of this being reopened so you can actually answer, I'd appreciate if you could delete that comment and repost, sans `remainder`.

Comment: You can use [`std::trunc(x/y);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/trunc) for quotient and [`std::fmod(x,y);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) for remainder. I don't know of any equivalent of div for floats.