# remquo Results Not Making Sense

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, division, modulo

I read [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remquo) that `remquo` should return:

> If successful, returns the floating-point remainder of the division `x/y` as defined in std::remainder, and a value whose sign is the sign of `x/y` and whose magnitude is congruent *modulo 2<sup>n</sup>*
>    to the magnitude of the integral quotient of `x/y`, where *n* is an implementation-defined integer greater than or equal to *3*.

Now clearly I've misunderstood all that techno-speak cause I thought that I was going to get back the fractional result of the division. Instead this operation:

```
int quot;
const float rem = remquo(7.0F, 4.0F, &quot);
```

Sets `quot` to *2* and `rem` to *-1.0*! I can see how that is valid because *4.0 * 2 = 8.0* and *7.0 - 8.0 = -1.0*. But why are we using a `quot` that will result in a negative `rem`? Shouldn't I be getting back a `quot` of *1* and a `rem` of *3.0*?

Comment: Are you talking about C or C++? They are different languages.

Comment: @Olaf This is a C function I'm asking about and is implemented the same in both languages. If you can explain it to me in C you've explained it to me in C++. Alternatively if you can explain it to me in C++ you're explained it to me in C.

Comment: You are not citing the C standard, but the C++ standard.

Comment: @Olaf It's the same as the C documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/remquo

Comment: @JonathanMee Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630321/why-does-c-output-negative-numbers-when-using-modulo

Comment: It is not and clearly cannot be, because there is no `std::` in C. However, it is congruent. But note that cppreference is no authoritative ressource. As far as I understand, for `r = remquo(x, y, &q)` it should be `x == q * y + r`. That is the same as for the remainder in general. It just seems `q` is somehow modulo `pow(2, n)` (I'm not sure about that part in the spec). It might become more surprisingly with larger `x` and/or non-power of two values.

Comment: @Olaf The spec cannot say that `*quot` receives the integral quotient because the integral quotient of two `float`s does not in general fit in an `int`. Instead, only the low bits of the integral quotient are provided. The spec is just saying that at least 3 of the least significant bits will be shown, in an unclear manner.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I had not problems about the "integral" part, but the modulo. While understood what it does, the reason was not clear to me. A short footnote would have been very welcome. But maybe one has to know  IEC 60559 to understand this fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is about the value returned by `remquo`, it is entirely about `std::remainder`, since that part of `remquo`'s behavior is defined directly as identical to that of `std::remainder`.

`std::remainder` provides the IEEE 754 remainder operation, which is different from `fmod` in that the `fmod` of two positive values can be expected to be always positive, whereas the IEEE 754 remainder is defined with respect to the integral quotient `q` as the **nearest** integer to the mathematical quotient x/y, so that `remainder = x - y*q` produces a negative result each time the mathematical quotient rounds **up** to the next integer.

The IEEE 754 remainder operation is the one being discussed in the [question “Math.IEEERemainder returns negative results.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158120/math-ieeeremainder-returns-negative-results-why) so you might want to read it and the accepted answer although they are about a different programming language.

Note: the part of the specification about the quotient being “congruent modulo 2<sup>n</sup> to the magnitude of the integral quotient” simply means that you do not get the entire integral quotient, which indeed might not fit an `int` type (think of `remquo(FLT_MAX, 1.0f, ...)`. Instead, you get an implementation-defined number of the least significant bits of the integral quotient. The implementation-defined number of bits that you get must be at least three, but can be more.

Comment: Thanks for clarification about that "congruent" part. The standards (C and C++) really could have been more clear about that it is just to fit the value into an integer. I just wonder why they just use three bits, because an `int` has at least 15 magnitude bits.

Comment: @Olaf The sort of people who would use `remquo` often only care about the last few bits of the integral quotient. Consider `remquo(…, M_PI_2, …)` (and that's a bit of a bad example because you might really be more interested in the remainder in the division by the real π, not the floating-point approximation of it, but bear with me): you might want to know if the integer quotient is even or odd, perhaps if it's congruent to 0, 1, 2 or 3 modulo 4, but not care so much about the higher-order bits.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I actually try to avoid floating point when possible (and until now, I was lucky in my C projects;-)

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I just encountered the same behavior as OP, which surprised me because [the documentation for the function I called](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/remquo-remquof-remquol?view=msvc-150) claims that "The remquo function calculates the floating-point remainder f of x / y such that x = i * y + f, where i is an integer, **f has the same sign as x**, and the absolute value of f is less than the absolute value of y."  Can you confirm that claim in the manpage is pure baloney?

Comment: @BenVoigt This documentation is problematic in at least two ways: the one you found, and the fact that it says “approximate magnitude of the quotient” which is a terrible way of stating that the three **lowest-order** bits of the quotient are the only ones that are guaranteed correct (“magnitude” implies that the highest-order bits of the quotient are the ones that can be relied on).

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is correct; as stated in std::remainder, the quotient is rounded to nearest integer, then the remainder could be negative.

If you are working with integer, I suggest you the C function div()